# How to stretch custom dropdown to whole grid width in zurb foundation

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a custom dropdown in my layout and it width depends on lenght of list items (by design i think).
I want to stretch this dropdown to whole grid width (width: 100%) but style in the class or inlined doesn't work. In my rendered source codei see that is injected inline style width calculated by any foundation script and i don't have idea how to override it. Any solutions?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="twelve columns">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="eight columns " style="background-color:red">
                some content
        </div>
        <div class="four columns " style="background-color:blue">
            <form class="custom">       
                <select style="display: none;">
                    <option value="1">opt a</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="2">opt b</option>
                    <option value="3">opt c</option>
                    <option value="4">opt d</option>
                </select>
                <div class="custom dropdown">
                    <a class="current " href="#" >
                        opt b
                    </a>
                    <a class="selector" href="#"></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>opt a</li>
                        <li class="selected">opt b</li>
                        <li>opt c</li>
                        <li>opt d</li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
form.custom div.custom.dropdown {
    width:100% !important;
}
form.custom div.custom.dropdown ul {
    width:100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using .scss foundation files, you can add to your app.scss:

```
//foundation 4 syntax
form.custom {
  .dropdown {
    @include grid-column($columns:12,$float:left);
  }
```

Or you can find out what css is used for .twelve and add to your combobox

Answer (score 0):

3 quick observerations...your are missing an `</div>`  for the first `<div class="row">` declaration, and the other observation is that you have the dropdown set in the div with 4 columns, so are you trying to make the dropdown 100% width of the four columns, or 100% width of the whole app?  Also, what version of foundation are you using?  Third observation, you are using syntax from foundation 3 and below.  The new syntax for 4 & 5 is `<div class="row"><div class="large-12 columns"></div></div>`...notice the "large-12".  So my answer is, add the missing end div, and use the appropriate grid syntax.  If this doesn't help you, please setup something in jsfiddle so we know what version of foundation and jquery you are using and can see the actual problem in action.  Hope this helped.